# Fan startup Ubuntu

Tags: fan

After last Ubuntu upgrade to 18.04 my fans are not working from the laptop startup. So they are getting on when my laptop is on 50 celsius. It's not critical but I want them to work from startup. Laptop is Dell G3 3579. Do you know some fan program or how to get them to work from startup?

Comment: The fans shouldn't turn on unless there's excess heat... so they shouldn't run from startup. Starting at 50 celsius is perfectly fine. They should speed up as the temp gets higher.